# Highest operation, a 'constant', lacks side-effects [MISRA 2004 Rule 14.2]

Tags: c++, lint, misra

Hi,                                                                                             This is a part of my code and getting some MISRA warning for this logic 
code:

```
#define NASSERT(x) std::_nassert(x)

void fun( 
         const uint8_t  * restrict  src ,
         uint8_t        * restrict  dst
){
    NASSERT(((int32_t) src % 8) == 0); //line 1
    NASSERT(((int32_t) dst % 8) == 0); //line 2
}
```

Warnings:(at both line 1 and line 2)

```
Warning 522: Highest operation, a 'constant', lacks side-effects [MISRA 2004 Rule 14.2]
Error 40: Undeclared identifier 'std'
```

Can you please guide me to resolve this ...

Comment: What is this? Misra Overflow? http://stackoverflow.com/users/3178558/ashwin?tab=questions

Comment: My answer below answers many of those questions at once! :)

Answer (score 3):

You are using a MISRA checker for C, while you are programming in C++.

MISRA C:2004 is for the C programming language.

You should be using [MISRA C++:2008](http://www.misra-cpp.com/Activities/MISRAC/tabid/171/Default.aspx).